# Equivalent to performance diagnostic tools; SQL Trace and TKPROF - CockroachDB

Tags: query-performance, cockroachdb

What are the performance diagnostic tools in CockroachDB?

Any equivalent to TKPROF?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB has introduced some really awesome features to get you started with analyzing query performance and tracing them ina. distributed system.

To begin, check out these two pages:

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/sql-tuning-with-explain.html

and

https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/stable/show-trace.html

For tracing, you can also set those on a cluster level with a cluster setting. This will allow queries over a certain threshold of time to be dumped into a text file with their traces.